# Is it OK to use an HFS+ start disk with High Sierra?

Tags: startup, high-sierra, hfs+, apfs

I have a clone of my internal SSD on an HFS+ partition of an external drive. I was wondering if there are issues with using such a disk as a startup disk with High Sierra.

Comment: macOS High Sierra supports both HFS+ and APFS as the file system of a Startup Disk, so why would you think there's going to be any problem?

Comment: "I have a clone of my internal SSD on an HFS+ partition of an external drive" (which either means `dd if=/dev/disk0 of=/dev/disk2s2` or `dd if=/dev/disk0 of=/Volumes/External/disk.image`) doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: @klanomath it means Carbon Copy Cloner, source=internal SSD, Target=some partition on external volume.

Comment: @user3439894 Appart from just "not knowing", part of my concern is that MacOS might have set preferences/config files on my SSD that tell the OS to expect an APFS disk and that cloning that onto an HFS+ and then using it a a startup disk might create problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - High Sierra fully supports running / booting from HFS+ since it doesn’t even change any system over to APFS except for Apple SSD based systems. Fusion drives and spinning HDD hard drives all remain on HFS+ as do all external drives connected to your High Sierra system.